# Laravel - How to set a message on progress bar

Tags: php, laravel, symfony, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

I'm trying the same example as provided on [Laravel docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/artisan#writing-output):

```
$users = App\User::all();

$this->output->progressStart(count($users));

foreach ($users as $user) {
    print "$user->name\n";

    $this->output->progressAdvance();
}

$this->output->progressFinish();
```

And this works well. I want to customize the progress bar (see [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console/helpers/progressbar.html#customizing-the-progress-bar)) but `$this->output->setMessage('xpto');` gives:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Illuminate\Console\OutputStyle::setFormat()
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The object returned by `$this->command->getOutput()` is a instance of Symfony's `Symfony\Component\Console\Style\SymfonyStyle`, which provides the methods `progressStart()`, `progressAdvance()` and `progressFinish()`.

The `progressStart()` method dynamically creates an instance of `Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\ProgressBar` object and appends it to your output object, so you can manipulate it using `progressAdvance()` and `progressFinish().`

Unfortunately, Symfony maintainers decided to keep both the `$progressBar` property and the `getProgressBar()` method as private, so you can't access the actual ProgressBar instance directly via your output object if you used `progressStart()` to start it.

**createProgressBar() to the rescue!**

However, there's an undocumented method called `createProgressBar($max)` that returns you a shiny brand new ProgressBar object that you can play with.

So, you can just do the following:

```
$progress = $this->command->getOutput()->createProgressBar(100);
```

And do whatever you want with it using the [Symfony's docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console/helpers/progressbar.html) page you provided. For example:

```
$this->info("Creating progress bar...\n");

$progress = $this->command->getOutput()->createProgressBar(100);

$progress->setFormat("%message%\n %current%/%max% [%bar%] %percent:3s%%");

$progress->setMessage("100? I won't count all that!");
$progress->setProgress(60);

for ($i = 0;$i<40;$i++) {
    sleep(1);
    if ($i == 90) $progress->setMessage('almost there...');
    $progress->advance();
}

$progress->finish();
```

I hope it helps. ;)

Comment: i get error `Call to undefined method UsersTableSeeder::info()` and `Undefined property: UsersTableSeeder::$output`. What im doing wrong?

Comment: Confirming this works for Laravel 5.8... what explained Laravel's official docs didn't work for me. Using **setFormat()** first worked.

Comment: In recent versions of Laravel you should use `$this->command->getOutput()` instead of `$this->output`.